# Coloring Points in a DateListPlot

Tags: color, date-and-time

I want to plot a time series so that positive values appear in red and negative values in green.

I have tried all kind of variants of the following, which just plots everything in the last color specified (Green in this case).  Also tried with ColorFunction, to no avail.

Maybe it's just me, but I find these trivial plotting issues are some of the most complex and time consuming to figure out in the Wolfram Language.

```
tsData = TimeSeries[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100], {Range[100]}];

   DateListPlot[tsData,Joined->False,Filling->Axis,PlotStyle->{If[#>0,Red,Green]&/@tsData["Values"]}]
```

Comment: Please post an example of `tsData`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

The solution by @kirma

```
DateListPlot[List /@ Normal[tsData], Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis,
  PlotStyle -> (If[# > 0, Red, Green] & /@ tsData["Values"])]
```

**Original**

- I don't kown how to make `DateListPlot` work,so here we only use `ListPlot`.
- The `PlotStyle` using `(If[# > 0, Red, Green] & /@ tsData["Values"])` instead of `{If[# > 0, Red, Green] & /@ tsData["Values"]}`

```
ListPlot[List /@ MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, tsData["Values"]], 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotStyle -> (If[# > 0, Red, Green] & /@ tsData["Values"])]
```

[image]

Comment: For `DateListPlot` use `List /@ Normal[tsData]` and `Joined -> False`.

Comment: @kirma  Thanks! updated.

Comment: Firstly, if you have zero values in the time series these show up as unwanted points on the x-axis in the plot.  Not an issue, perhaps, if you only have one or two of them, but if you have many of them it ruins the plot.

Comment: Secondly, could your or  @kirma explain more clearly what he means in his comment about DateListPlot, which is specifically what I want to know about?  A code example would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @MMAUser `List /@ Normal[tsData]` converts the `TimeSeries` data into a list where every data point (date and value) is enclosed in its own single-point time series, which are given individually the colour using the list of colours given on `PlotStyle`. Nothing more fancy than that.

Comment: @MMAUser If you want to skip plotting points which are zero you can change the function inside `PlotStyle` to `Piecewise[{{Red, # > 0}, {Green, # < 0}}, None] &` or something similar.